# Conda cannot remove environment called "tensorflow"

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, anaconda, conda

I just run the following command to create a Conda environment:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

However, I want to delete it now. When I try doing:

```
conda remove -n tensorflow
```

or

```
conda remove --name tensorflow
```

I get the following error:

```
CondaValueError: no package names supplied,
       try "conda remove -h" for more details
```

However, if I try and see which environments I have, I can see:

```
base                  *  C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3
flask_env                C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\envs\flask_env
tensorflow               C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow
```

My idea is that I have called the environment with the same name of the package tensorflow.. even though I don't have tensorflow installed in the "base" environment

Comment: try `conda env remove --name tensorflow`

Comment: Damn you're good. It worked! Can you explain me why this works?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm assuming `conda` is getting tripped up by the fact that `tensorlow` is a package as well as the name of an environment, and the plain `conda remove` command can also be used to remove packages. So, I know that you can do `conda env remove ...` to force it to only consider environments.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to write it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would try:

```
conda env remove --name tensorflow
```

Which forces `conda` to only consider environments, since a

```
conda remove
```

command can also be used to remove packages. I suspect `conda` is being tripped up by the fact that `tensorflow` is a package name *and*  an environment name.